# Points with coordinates in France in Google maps displayed near Somalia with Google maps API

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I started creating a map with google Maps Api and I used the answer by geozip to the following question to create it:
[GeoJSON Point name & description not displayed when using Google Map API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050593/geojson-point-name-description-not-displayed-when-using-google-map-api-v3)

The coordinates that I checked in google Maps to display 2 points in France appear near Somalia when inserted from the Json file through the Google Maps Api.

I tried to change these points to the coordinates originally present in the example (working example submitted as an answer to the question I linked above) and they were displayed at their normal location.

I unfortunately can't post the screenshots as I do not have 10 reputations and this is the first question I ever post.

Does anyone have an idea about how I could fix this coordinates issue or about what I am missing?

Thank you,

Mariella

Here is the json file (with French coordinates that get displayed near Somalia):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [47.394500, 0.684640]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "Point A",
            "description": "Description point A"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [47.810893, 0.688451]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "Point B",
            "description": "Description point B"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Here is the code for the map:

```
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
// Create a simple map.
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: { lat: 47.507214, lng: 2.331543},
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.close();
});

// Load the associated GeoJSON
var url = 'linktojson.json';
map.data.loadGeoJson(url);

// Set event listener for each feature.
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
 infowindow.setContent(event.feature.getProperty('name')+"  
<br>"+event.feature.getProperty('description'));
 infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
 infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-34)});
 infowindow.open(map);
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You points appear near Somalia because you are changing the order of the Latitude and Longitude in the GeoJSON format.

From [the documentation](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions):

> A position is represented by an array of numbers. There must be at
>   least two elements, and may be more. The order of elements must follow
>   x, y, z order (easting, northing, altitude for coordinates in a
>   projected coordinate reference system, or ***longitude, latitude***,
>   altitude for coordinates in a geographic coordinate reference system).

According to this, your GeoJSON file must be as follows:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [0.684640, 47.394500]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "Point A",
            "description": "Description point A"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [0.688451, 47.810893]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "Point B",
            "description": "Description point B"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Hope it helps.